# Inflation rate with the CPI multiples country, with R

Tags: r, database, dplyr, lubridate, quantmod

I have to calculate the inflation rate from 2015 to 2019. I have to do this with the CPI, which I have for each month during the 4 years. This means that I have to calculate the percentage growth rate for the same month last year.

They ask me for the calculation of several countries and then calculate or show the average for the period 2015-2019.

This is my database:

```
 data <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/6cetukKb")
```

[image: Data]

I have tried the quantmod, dplyr, lubridate packages, but I can't do the CPI conversion.

I tried this but I know it is not correct:

```
data$year <- year(data$date)
anual_cpi <- data %>%    group_by(year) %>% summarize(cpi = mean(Argentina))
  anual_cpi$adj_factor <- anual_cpi$cpi/anual_cpi$cpi[anual_cpi$year == 2014]
```

**

### UPDATE

**

my teacher gave us a hint on how to get the result, but when I try to add it to the code, I get an error.

```
data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = Antigua_Barbuda:Barbados) %>%
  group_by(name, year) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  mutate((change=(x-lag(x,1))/lag(x,1)*100))



| Antigua_Barbuda   | -1.55     |
|-----------------  |-------    |
| Argentina         | 1.03      |
| Aruba             | -1.52     |
| Bahamas           | -1.56     |
| Barbados          | -1.38     |
```

where "value" corresponds to the average inflation for each country during the entire period 2015-2019

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` methods

```
library(data.table)
melt(fread("https://pastebin.com/raw/6cetukKb"), 
    id.var = c('date', 'year', 'period', 'periodName'))[, 
    .(value = mean(value)), .(variable, year)][,
      adj_factor := value/value[year == 2014]][]
#           variable year     value adj_factor
# 1: Antigua_Barbuda 2014  96.40000  1.0000000
# 2: Antigua_Barbuda 2015  96.55833  1.7059776
# 3: Antigua_Barbuda 2016  96.08333  1.0146075
# 4: Antigua_Barbuda 2017  98.40833  0.9900235
# 5: Antigua_Barbuda 2018  99.62500  0.5822618
# 6: Antigua_Barbuda 2019 101.07500  1.0484959
# 7:       Argentina 2014  56.60000  1.0000000
# ..
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read your data with `header = TRUE` since the first row are the names of the columns. Then get your data in long format which makes it easy to do the calculation.

After this you can perform whichever calculation you want. For example, to perform the same steps as your attempt i.e divide all the values with the value in the year 2014 for each country you can do.

```
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/6cetukKb", header = TRUE)

data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = Antigua_Barbuda:Barbados) %>%
  group_by(name, year) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value)) %>%
  mutate(adj_factor = value/value[year == 2014])

#  name             year value adj_factor
#   <chr>           <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1 Antigua_Barbuda  2014  96.4      1    
# 2 Antigua_Barbuda  2015  96.6      1.00 
# 3 Antigua_Barbuda  2016  96.1      0.997
# 4 Antigua_Barbuda  2017  98.4      1.02 
# 5 Antigua_Barbuda  2018  99.6      1.03 
# 6 Antigua_Barbuda  2019 101.       1.05 
# 7 Argentina        2014  56.6      1    
# 8 Argentina        2015  64.0      1.13 
# 9 Argentina        2016  89.9      1.59 
#10 Argentina        2017 113.       2.00 
# … with 20 more rows
```